# View spec does not run controller before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rspec, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this failing view spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "ideas/edit" do
  before(:each) do
    @idea = assign(:idea, stub_model(Idea,
      :phase => 1,
      :brief => "MyText",
      :image => "MyString",
      :active => true,
      :activity_list => ["Science & Technology"]
    ))
  end

  it "renders the edit idea form" do
    render

    # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat matchers
    assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", idea_path(@idea), "post" do
      assert_select "textarea#idea_brief[name=?]", "idea[brief]"
      assert_select "input#idea_industry[name=?]", "idea[industry]"
    end
  end
end
```

The error:

```
  1) ideas/edit renders the edit idea form
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/ideas/_long_form.html.erb:27:in `block in _app_views_ideas__long_form_html_erb___781758430_98755320'
     # ./app/views/ideas/_long_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_ideas__long_form_html_erb___781758430_98755320'
     # ./app/views/ideas/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_ideas_edit_html_erb__967817323_98657300'
     # ./spec/views/ideas/edit.html.erb_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the relevant line of the rendered form. The @categories variable is initialized in the controller, but is nil for some reason when the spec is run.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :category_list, "Categories" %>
  <%= f.select :category_list, @categories, {selected:@idea.category_list}, {:multiple => true, :style => "height:180px;"} %>
</div>
```

In my controller I have:

```
before_action :set_categories, only: [:edit, :update]
...
def set_categories
      @categories = [
        "Arts & Entertainment",
        "Science & Technology",
        "Business & Finance",
        "Software & Internet",
        "Retail",
        "Education",
        "Energy & Utilities",
        "Food & Health",
        "Media & Communications",
        "Other"
      ]
    end
```

When troubleshooting I tried removing the "only:" restrictions and received the same error.

Interestingly, the spec passes if I add the following line to its before(:each) block:

```
@categories = "Other"
```

It seems that the spec is not running the before_action in the controller. Is this expected behavior? What have I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

This post indicates that the view spec is intended to run in isolation from the controller and that the variable must be set in the spec: http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/37 under "Instance Variables and Rendering The View"

I added this line right before "render" in my spec

```
assign :categories, []
```